# Using Scikit Learn in a classification setting

Tags: python, twitter, scikit-learn, tweepy

I have a question regarding the logic of programming and what would be the smartest way of doing what I want to do.

I want to do a "simple" Twitter sentiment classification, either classifying a tweet as positive or negative (maybe also neutral, not sure yet). I wanted to listen to the twitter stream with tweepy and store the incoming tweets in a database. I was thinking that since the ToS of Twitter forbid the storage of tweets that I would want to process the tweets while listening to the stream. Meaning, I want to lowercase them, remove add. whitespaces, strip some words etc. etc., everything that I need to classify them. Then use a pre-trained model to classify each tweet and then only store the tweet ID and the sentiment of the tweet in the database and not the tweet.

Now my concern: In every Tutorial about scikit learn classifiers there is always more than one document to be classified. The .predict function also requires an "array-like, sparse matrix" http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict

So would it even be possible to classify only one tweet at a time? The other option would be to disregard the ToS and store the tweets in the database, do all the processing and classification at the end of the analysis (it is interesting to watch the sentiment of whatever over a longer period in time, or even monitor it constantly) and delete the tweets then.

What would be the smartest way? I'm fairly new to programming so I want to learn the logic.

Comment: I'm voting to close, as this question is too broad, however the answer to this part of the question,"So would it even be possible to classify only one tweet at a time?", is "Yes".

Comment: Ok, sorry but thanks anyways.